# Laravel Jetstream and AWS SES change sender email address

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, laravel-jetstream

I am using:

- Laravel Jetstream Inertia
- Laravel 8
- Amazon Simple Email Service (Sendbox)

**The problem:**

I am trying to setup the password reset system for my application.
The problem is that Fortify automatically sends the password reset email using the user's email address (ie: if the user with email *test@example.com* tries to reset the password, Laravel will try to send an email from *test@example.com*).

Because of how Amazon SES works, you can **only** send email from verified idetities. I have my email address (*info@openlabvr.com*) verified on SES, and I can send regular emails in Laravel just by specifing `->from()`. Everything works fine here.

But of course, when Laravel tries to send the reset password email using the user's email adddress, I get an error from SES:

`<Code>MessageReje (truncated...) MessageRejected (client): Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-WEST-1: test@example.com - <ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/"> <Error> <Type>Sender</Type> <Code>`

**What I have tried:**

I tried to set `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="info@openlabvr.com"` in my `.env` file, and  to run `php artisan config:clear` and/or `php artisan optimize`, but nothing changed.

I also tried to set the `Source` option in the `services.php` file like so:

```
'ses' => [
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'us-east-1'),
        'options' => [
            'Source' => 'info@openlabvr.com',
        ],
    ],
```

But again, nothing changed.

Lastly, I tried to to change my user's email address from *test@example.com* to *info@openlabvr.com*, and that worked as expected.

**tldr**

How can I force Fortify to use info@openlabvr.com as the sender address to reset the password of my user?

Comment: Seems like an odd decision by fortify to do this. I for one would be really suspicious of an email coming from my own email address to my own email address saying to reset my password.

Comment: That's what I am thinking as well. I tried to look up in the Fortify documentation, but I didn't find anything about it. Am I missing something else maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved.

The problem was with AWS SES and not actually with Fortify
Under verified identities, on the SES console, it says:

> A verified identity is a domain, subdomain, or email address you use
> to send email through Amazon SES

In reality, this is not true. You also need to verify the identity of the receiver's email address.
Therefore, the only solution for my problem is to apply for a production SES account, rather than the sandbox one I had.